# Symfony with queryBuiler and understanding performance

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine, query-builder

I have a query that returns a single product with its relationships. I want this page to load fast, so query performance is very important for me. However, I am having big performance issues and I don`t really understand how this could be fixed in Symfony.

This is my query:

```
public function findProduct(string $id, string $locale)
    {
        $dateNow = date('Y-m-d') . ' 23:59:59';
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');
        $qb->innerJoin('p.productRegionData', 'prd');
//        $qb->addSelect('prd');
        $qb->innerJoin('prd.region', 'r', 'WITH', "r.iso = '" . $locale . "'");
        $qb->leftJoin('p.productCategories', 'pc');
//        $qb->addSelect('pc');
        $qb->innerJoin('p.productSeoUrls', 'psu');
//        $qb->addSelect('psu');
        $qb->leftJoin('p.productDiscounts', 'pd', 'WITH', "pd.active = 1 AND pd.discountFrom <= '" . $dateNow . "' AND pd.discountTo >= '" . $dateNow . "'");
//        $qb->addSelect('pd');
        $qb->leftJoin('p.productWallThicknesses', 'pwt');
//        $qb->addSelect('pwt');
        $qb->innerJoin('p.productImages', 'pi');
//        $qb->addSelect('pi');
        $qb->leftJoin('p.productFloorDimensions', 'pfd');
//        $qb->addSelect('pfd');
        $qb->leftJoin('p.productWindows', 'pw');
//        $qb->addSelect('pw');
        $qb->leftJoin('p.productDoors', 'pdo');
//        $qb->addSelect('pdo');
        $qb->leftJoin('p.productAttributes', 'pa');
//        $qb->addSelect('pa');
        $qb->leftJoin('pa.attribute', 'at');
//        $qb->addSelect('at');
        $qb->andWhere('p.id = :id');
        $qb->setParameter('id', $id);
        $qb->groupBy('p');
        return $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
    }
```

As you can see this query returns a product with multiple relationships. Now there are 3 scenarios that I have tried and each of them solves one problem, but another problem occurs.

SCENARIO 1: Using `groupBy` without `addSelect()`.

This is the fastest in terms of performance, however each time I access a relationship, a new query is excecuted(if I understand that is because I am not using `addSelect()` and thats how Doctrine works). This is pretty quick, however I am concerned with the large amount of queries being executed for a single product:

[image]

[image]

SCENARIO 2: Not using `groupBy` and using `addSelect()`

Performance wise this scenario is the slowest because I am running out of php memory(its 128MB but it still shouldn`t take that much?). However the number of queries is reduced drastically since I am using` addSelect()`

SCENARIO 3: Using `groupBy` and using `addSelect()`

The fastest solution in terms of performance, however, using this will return a single entity from a relationship. For example if I have 5 images, it will return only 1 image, which is of course not what I want.

So now I am really struggling to understand how this should be achieved in the best way? Which scenario is the best, maybe there is a better one? Maybe I should just use raw sql? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a product entity with all these relationships already? Can you post your product entity?

Comment: The addSelect causes the joined entity to be loaded as part of the query.  So you avoid a later lazy query but it will slow up the current query.  Each join adds to the amount of data being transferred and makes the Doctrine mapper work harder.  It might be worth while to dump the sql that Doctrine uses to see what is going on.  Might also be worth while to write sql by hand and use the database's analyze tools to perhaps identify the bottle necks.  It could be that you are just missing an index someplace.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have a relation between all these tables?

Your query is restarting in a loop.

Are you just selecting from the same table?
I don't understand your inner join syntax.

```
<?php
$queryBuilder
    ->select('u.id', 'u.name', 'p.number')
    ->from('users', 'u')
    ->innerJoin('u', 'phonenumbers', 'p', 'u.id = p.user_id')
```

Comment: The OP is using a package called Doctrine ORM which in turn has it's own object oriented version of SQL called DQL(Doctrine Query Language).  Suffice it to say that Doctrine knows how to join tables based on it's mapping information.